# Docker: disable pulling from remote registry

Tags: docker

When I mistype things it tries to search in the central registry. How to disable it completely?

Is there an option to clear that URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the a redhat clone with the rpms from centos extras, they have a parameter to do that:

```
--block-registry hostname
```

This is a RedHat extension (see [here](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/04/15/understanding-the-changes-to-docker-search-and-docker-pull-in-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-1/)) which I don't think was accepted upstream (considering [13450](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13450))

Answer (score 2):

As a reference, right now (docker 1.9, Nov 2015):

- [`pull.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e2417e3e926d2b45049a663bc62828a70fbfab2a/graph/pull.go#L80) looks for pull endpoints:

  ```
  s.registryService.LookupPullEndpoints()
  ```
- [`registry/service.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ef4b053b9064888eadf25e48f7f1d4d5896da8fb/registry/service.go#L127) looks for V2 endpoint:

  ```
  s.lookupEndpoints(repoName)
  ```
- [`registry/service_v2.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ef4b053b9064888eadf25e48f7f1d4d5896da8fb/registry/service_v2.go#L32) appends `DefaultV2Registry`:

  ```
  endpoints = append(endpoints, APIEndpoint{
      URL:          DefaultV2Registry,
  ```
- [`registry/config_unix.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/729c9a97822ebee2c978a322d37060454af6bc66/registry/config_unix.go#L10) includes `DefaultV2Registry`:

  ```
  DefaultV2Registry = "https://registry-1.docker.io"
  ```

So until there is an option to *not* look for that endpoint, `docker pull` will still include that central default V2 registry.

Comment: what a pity ... 
IMHO for the suitability to corporate environments one shall be in the position to restrict the places from where images can be pulled (e.g. to exclude the dockerhub) same as you can restrict maven not to download the dependencies from the web, but only from a corporate system.

Comment: @JuergenKlasen I agree. I am looking into a wrapper like http://port.us.org/documentation.html in order to see if that feature is there.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a json file in

   /etc/containers/policy.json

with content:

```
   {
  "default": [
    {
      "type": "insecureAcceptAnything"
    }
  ],
  "transports":
  {
    "docker":
    {
      "docker.io": [{"type":"reject"}]
    }
  }
}
```

2. reload the daemon

   systemctl daemon-reload
3. restart docker or crio or any container technology we use

   ```
   eg: systemctl restart docker
   eg: systemctl restart crio
   ```

NOTE: to block multiple repo's:
just add the repos in this format in the docker block in the above json:

```
"docker":
    {
      "abc.repo1.io": [{"type":"reject"}],
      "abc.repo2.io": [{"type":"reject"}],
      "docker.io": [{"type":"reject"}]
    }
```