# How to prevent docker from searching docker hub

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerhub

I'm standing up a few docker hosts to run in a production environment. We want all of our images to have to go through our container pipeline and we do not want to be able to pull images from Docker Hub (security concerns).

How can I stop docker being able to pull images from dockerhub? Ideally I would like to do this via configuring the docker daemon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: disable pulling from remote registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774267/docker-disable-pulling-from-remote-registry)

Comment: We don't use the docker RPM from the extras repo, we use it from the docker_ce repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is not possible to prevent docker for searching docker hub..

But **it is possible** to prevent/avoid pulling image from docker hub. And it this case, all searching on docker hub will find nothing.

To do it: you must concatenate your private registry url(without https:// or http://) with your image name like:
`FROM myprivate_registry/myimagename:if_version` or `FROM myprivate_registry:registry_port/myimagename:if_version`

Also, you can say to docker to use your private registry as its first registry and docker hub will become the second:

```
`ADD_REGISTRY='--add-registry myregistry'` or `INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry myregistry'`
```

Comment: Having looked through the ticket mentioned in a comment by @Rumid it appears as though docker hub is hard coded, so I think that this is the closest we can get