# Is it possible to restrict access to public repository like Docker Hub and pull docker images from private repository only?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Due to security concerns, I am looking to restrict pulling docker images from any other source (including Docker Hub) than a secure private repository.

Is there some docker configuration to achieve this?

The closest I can achieve this is using content-trust, is there some other option?

Comment: Does it answer your question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079176/how-to-prevent-docker-from-searching-docker-hub